# Import project from Netbeans into Eclipse, exception with .txt file

Tags: java, file, stream

I made a project in Netbeans and archived it as .zip. Then, after I import it in Eclipse it doesn't find a specific txt file from where I read. I tried to include it everywhere in the project, in every folder, but it still can't find it. I did refresh the project page.

```
    public static void Muser() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {// lista user 
    int nr = 0;
    FileInputStream fstream = null;
    fstream = new FileInputStream("user.txt");
    // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
    // DataInputStream f = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String cerere = br.readLine();

    while (cerere != null) {
        m.linie++;

        U user;
        String[] date = cerere.split(" ");

        Key cheie = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede").generateKey();
        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        String stringCheie = encoder.encode(cheie.getEncoded());
        System.out.println(date[0] + " KUT: " + stringCheie);

        user = new U(date[0], cheie, Integer.parseInt(date[1]), Integer.parseInt(date[2]));
        m.adaugaU(date[0]);
        userList.add(user);
        cerere = br.readLine();

    }
}
```

It gives me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: user.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at server.Server.Muser(Server.java:319)
at server.Server.main(Server.java:345)
```

I solved it, it was a path problem.

Comment: The exception is too clear. Path issue.

Comment: I know, but I have included the file everywhere in the project and it still doesn't find it

Answer (score 0):

> *"I have included the file everywhere in the project and it still doesn't find it"*

If you're using this "user.txt" relative path, in Eclipse, the file should be place directly in the project root

```
ProjectRoot
          user.txt
          src
          bin
```